# How to increase HTTP header size in jboss eap 6.1?

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, spring-security-kerberos

I am facing the issue with using spnego spring security extensions for implementing SSO and getting bad request (Error 400) for large spnego token.

I am using jboss-eap 6.1, how can I increase the size of HTTP header, I see no option in domain.xml/ standalone.xml

Comment: See the answer here:https://community.jboss.org/thread/235696

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is exactly what we have to do:
In jboss 6.1  domain.xml

locate  tag and add the below property to it.

```
<system-properties>
   <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.MAX_HEADER_SIZE" value="65535"/>
</system-properties>
```